# Paperclip and amazon s3 - image path includes bucket region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm uploading images using paperclip and amazon s3. The images are uploading to my bucket but I am unable to get the correct url in my view. 
The url I want is this:

```
s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app/model/images/000/000/005/original/image.jpeg
```

Instead I get this url:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/app/model/images/000/000/005/original/image.jpeg
```

It is just missing the  `s3-us-west` at the the start.

Using [this guideline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3), I tried to fix it by changing the default paperclip url structure.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
:url => "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
s3_credentials: {
  bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
  access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
  secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
  s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
 }
}
```

But that messed it up more and now I'm getting this path:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/app/model/publics3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't read far enough. Oops.

Added this to initializers/paperclip.rb:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```